# Upgrade from 1.9.2.3 to 1.9.3.1 Can not Upload Product Images in Admin

Tags: admin, adminhtml, product-images, magento1.9.3, magento1.9.3.1

From what I understand, Magento removed the Flash uploader. When I upgraded I did an FTP merge. I have since Deleted the folder:  `/skins/adminhtml/default/default/media/`

I do not have **CreareSEO** module

In Admin section: `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml` the following line is there:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/uploader.js</script></action>
```

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/` these lines are in:

```
<action method="addJs"><name>lib/uploader/flow.min.js</name></action>
<action method="addJs"><name>lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js</name></action
<action method="addJs"><name>lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js</action>
```

The only extension I can think of that would affect Admin would be Enhanced Admin Grids. In `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/bl/customgrid.xml` 
I added these:

```
<action method="addJs"><name>lib/uploader/flow.min.js</name></action>
<action method="addJs"><name>lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js</name></action>
<action method="addJs"><name>lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js</action>
```

There are no new errors in the errorlog

I have tried a bunch of other things and poked around everywhere I can think of on the site and looked at every answer I could find online with Google.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is a major problem that I need to resolve now. We cannot add products to the site without image.

Comment: You may try to clear js/css cache if merge js is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I am not positive that it is not a combination of things I did when I was working on this last night or not, but I realized while I had cleaned Magentos cache out and reindexed a bunch of times. I don't think I ever cleared the browsers cache. I have done so, and now it appears to be working correctly. Maybe this will help someone else to remember to do the same.

Comment: Also solved it for me, thanks! On Chrome I was able to do Shift + CMD/Ctrl + R!

Comment: This solved my issue. :D

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the browser.js from the header layout in admin or just rename it in the js/mage/adminhtml.

it will work fine.