# Magento 1.9.3.1 Unable to upload products after upgrade

Tags: product-images, image-upload, magento1.9.3.1

I recently upgraded from **1.9.2.4** to **1.9.3.1** and now we are unable to upload images. I had already applied the **SUPEE-8788** patch before and had already switched from the Adobe Flash to the new HTML5 uploader and that was working before.

I have looked in PHP and nginx error logs, but there is no error. I've also verified that the image is uploaded to the directory `mage_root/media/tmp/catalog/product` but it does not get moved out of the tmp folder. As far as I am aware all permissions are correct.

I've already tried the solutions listed at: [Upgrade from 1.9.2.3 to 1.9.3.1 Can not Upload Product Images in Admin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148717/upgrade-from-1-9-2-3-to-1-9-3-1-can-not-upload-product-images-in-admin) but did not have any luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have any core overwrites in app/code/local/mage?

Comment: @Haim no, everything there is base Magento.

Comment: is there an error in system.log or in your console?

Comment: @Haim no there are no errors in any logs. I did a grep on the entire magento var/log directory looking for strings related to this and found nothing. There are also no errors in the browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the browser.js from the header layout in admin or just rename it in the js/mage/adminhtml.

it will work fine.

Comment: My issue was actually that our cloudfront upload script had uploaded older versions of the needed JS files.